# jQuery, AJAX - content type: application/json - does it work in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

This is how I've been handling my ajax until now:

`@header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=".get_option('blog_charset'));`

and the js:

```
$.ajax(....
  ...
  success: function(response){
    var obj = eval('('+response+')'); 
    if(obj.somedata == ....)
  ...
```

And now I want to use `application/json` as content type so the javascript changes to:

```
$.ajax(....
  ...
  success: function(response){
    if(response.somedata == ....)
  ...
```

Looks better :)
But I'm curious to know if this will work in all browsers? So far it tested OK in FF, Opera and IE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. JSON is not so much browser-dependent/specific as it is Javascript-specific, so assuming you have a browser (any browser) that has a full implementation of javascript, then it will support JSON. [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works as long as your server sends proper content-type (application/json) and properly formated JSON data.

Also just for safety you could specify the response data type:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.somedata == ....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method also works across browsers =).